# qsort with pointer to pointer to void

Tags: c, qsort

`qsort` is working here, but if each member of array `v` occupies `sizeof(void *)`, why is `qsort` expecting `sizeof(int)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(int *)pa;
    int b = *(int *)pb;

    if (a > b)
        return +1;
    else
    if (b > a)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, a[] = {3, 1, 2, 0, 4};
    void **v;

    v = malloc(sizeof(void *) * 5);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        v[i] = &a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)v[i]);
    }
    qsort(v[0], 5, sizeof(int), comp); // why sizeof(int) if v is void **
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)v[i]);
    }
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: David: do you understand `v[i] = &a[i];` expression in your code, Why this is needed and why `v` is `void*` is correct here ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I have to use void ** (as abstraction for a generic container) to sort different types

Comment: Correct!, and `v[i] = &a[i]` is needed because you wants to sort `a[]` array, But in `qsort()` call you are passing `v` that doesn't contain about type of your array `a[]` hence you explicitly passing content information that `a[i]` elements are `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
qsort(v[0], 5, sizeof(int), comp); // why sizeof(int) if v is void **
```

The address of the start of the memory block to be sorted that you pass to `qsort` is

```
v[0] = &a[0]
```

the address of the initial element of `a`, so the array that you sort is `a`, not the block whose initial element `v` points to. `a`'s elements are `int`s, so `sizeof(int)` is the correct size.

If you want to sort the array of pointers, you need to pass the address of the first element in that array, `&v[0]`, or simply `v` to `qsort`. Then of course the size argument must be `sizeof (void*)`:

```
qsort(v, 5, sizeof(void*), cmp);
```

but for that, you can't use the comparison function you have, you need

```
int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    int a = *(int*)(*(void**)pa);
    int b = *(int*)(*(void**)pb);

    if (a > b)
        return +1;
    else
    if (b > a)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

or something similar. Since what is passed to the comparison function from `qsort` is the address of the things to compare, we need one indirection to get the pointers to compare, and since here we want to compare pointers by what `int` values they point to, we need the second indirection to get the pointed-to `int`s.

Comment: No, `qsort` passes `&a[i]` and `&a[j]` (computed via the `size` parameter) to `comp`, so it's correct. It may not be what was intended - if the intention was to sort the array of pointers - but as it turns out, the code is correct. Perhaps accidentally.

Comment: Yes, I know `&a[i]` and `&a[j]` are passed to the comparator and that's *exactly* what confuses me... I don't see how it's correct, I'm missing a level of indirection... maybe I should have a nap instead of hanging around on SO :)

Comment: got it Daniel, thanks, and yes, the intention was to sort the array of pointers, how to pass void ** to qsort in order to sort v (not a)?

Comment: @H2CO3 The call is actually `qsort(a, 5, sizeof(int), comp);` (well, `&a[0]` if one wants to make the conversion explicit). Do you see why that works? The `v` is just fluff that doesn't affect the sort at all.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, correct, that's what I was missing. Silly me. Aaaargh. :/

Comment: @DavidRF To sort the array of pointers, you need to change the comparison function (and the call). Give me a few minutes to type that up.